# How to find repeated values of the column in table and perform sorting across columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am doing sorting in the given table, I have asked to hide and show the values based on sorting For example: If user is clicking (**Credit** Column, then **outstanding** and **allbal** column value should be null for both **ASC** and **DESC**) it's working fine. I want to perform sorting like if (**Debit** columns values are same I want to sort the **Debit** Column based on "**Date**"(**Asc** to **Desc**). If both "**Debit**" and "**Date**" Columns are same I want to sort **Debit** column based on "**visitorCode**"(**Asc** to **Desc**).

For example in Debit Column if I have 5 values (100, 100, 100, 200, 300) I want to display the **Debit** column values based on **Date** Column. If Date and **Debit** columns are same For example : Date column is having (2021-02-04, 2021-02-04, 2021-02-10, 2021-02-08)(YYYY-MM-DD) Debit Column (100,100,100,200,300) I want to perform sort Debit Column based on "**visitorCode**".

I've tried many ways to achieve this, unfortunately all of my logics are failed. Anybody can guide me how to perform above sorting. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
const props = {

    "rows" : 
    [{
        "visitiedDate": "2021-04-02",
        "visitorCode": [
            "ABC001"
        ], 
        "visittype": 1,
        "debit": 800,
        "credit": 100,
        "oustanding": 1000,
        "allbal":1000
    },
    {
        "visitiedDate": "2021-04-02",
        "visitorCode": [
            "ABC002"
        ], 
        "visittype": 1,
        "debit": 800,
        "credit": 100,
        "oustanding": 1000,
        "allbal":1000
    },
    {
        "visitiedDate": "2021-02-02",
        "visitorCode": [
            "ABC003"
        ], 
        "visittype": 2,
        "debit": 900,
        "credit": 100,
        "oustanding": 1000,
        "allbal":1000
    },
    {
        "visitiedDate": "2021-03-01",
        "visitorCode": [
            "ABC004"
        ], 
        "visittype": 2,
        "debit": 1000,
        "credit": 100,
        "oustanding": 1000,
        "allbal":1000
    },
    {
        "visitiedDate": "2021-04-02",
        "visitorCode": [
            "ABC005"
        ], 
        "visittype": 1,
        "debit": 500,
        "credit": 100,
        "oustanding": 1000,
        "allbal":1000
    }], 
    
    columns = [{
    "key": "date",
    "name": "Date",
    "isSort": true
  },
  
  {
    "key": "visittype",
    "name": "type",
    "isSort": true
  },
  
{
    "key": "vistiorCode",
    "name": "code",
    "isSort": false
  },
  
  {
    "key": "credit",
    "name": "camount",
    "isSort": true
  },
  
  {
    "key": "debit",
    "name": "damount",
    "isSort": true
  },

  {
    "key": "outstanding",
    "name": "outstandingBal",
  },
  
  {
    "key": "allbal",
    "name": "allBalance",
  },
]

const [col, setCol] = useState(columns)
const Rows = props.contractDetails; 
const TotalDetails = props.totalCount

function SortingRow(rows, col, sortMethod) {

  const sortRow = ((sortMethod === "ASC") || ((col === "type") || (col === "credit") || (col === "debit"))?
    rows.map(Details) => {
      if (col === "debit")
            return  Object.assign({}, Details, {outstanding: "", allbal: ""})   
      else  if(col === "credit"){
            return  Object.assign({}, Details, {outstanding: "", allbal: ""})   
            })
            : rows
  return sortMethod ?
    sortRow
    .slice()
    .sort(
      ({
        [col]: a
      }, {
        [col]: b
      }) =>
      (a === b ? 0 : a < b ? -1 : 1) *
      (sortMethod === "ASC" ? 1 : -1)
    }) :
    rows
}

const rows = col
  .slice()
  .reverse()
  .reduce(
    (sortedRows, {
      key: col,
      isSort,
      sortMethod
    }) =>
    isSort ? SortingRow(sortedRows, col, sortMethod) : sortedRows,
    Rows
  );

return (

  rows = {
    rows
  }
  col = {
    col
  }
  onSort = {
    (col, sortMethod) => setCol(
      cols.map(cl =>
        c.key === col ? Object.assign({}, cl, {
          sortMethod
        }) :
        cl
      )
    )
  }
)

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `Array#sort()` method:

```js
let rows = [
  {
    visitiedDate: "2021-04-02",
    visitorCode: ["ABC001"],
    visittype: 1,
    debit: 800,
    credit: 100,
    oustanding: 1000,
    allbal: 1000
  },
  {
    visitiedDate: "2021-04-02",
    visitorCode: ["ABC002"],
    visittype: 1,
    debit: 800,
    credit: 100,
    oustanding: 1000,
    allbal: 1000
  },
  {
    visitiedDate: "2021-02-02",
    visitorCode: ["ABC003"],
    visittype: 2,
    debit: 900,
    credit: 100,
    oustanding: 1000,
    allbal: 1000
  },
  {
    visitiedDate: "2021-03-01",
    visitorCode: ["ABC004"],
    visittype: 2,
    debit: 1000,
    credit: 100,
    oustanding: 1000,
    allbal: 1000
  },
  {
    visitiedDate: "2021-04-02",
    visitorCode: ["ABC005"],
    visittype: 1,
    debit: 500,
    credit: 100,
    oustanding: 1000,
    allbal: 1000
  }
];
console.log(
  rows.sort((a, b) =>
    a.debit < b.debit
      ? -1
      : 0 && new Date(a.visitiedDate) < new Date(b.visitiedDate)
      ? -1
      : 0 || (a.visitorCode[0] < b.visitorCode[0] ? -1 : 1)
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am little bit confused where I want to add the above code because for the current sorting I am using  (sortMethod === "ASC" ? 1 : -1). Could you please guide me where I want to use above logic which you've added. Thanks in advance